# Python CSV Parsing, Escaped Quote Character

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I am trying to parse a CSV file using the csv.reader, my data is separated by commas and each value starts and ends with quotation marks.  Example:

```
"This is some data", "New data", "More \"data\" here", "test"
```

My problem is with the third value, the data I get which has quotation marks within it has an escape character to show it is part of the data.  The python CSV reader does not use this escape character so it results in incorrect parsing.

I tried code like below:

```
    with open(filepath) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='\\"')
```

But I get an error complaining the quotechar is not 1 character.

My current solution is just to replace all characters \" characters with a single quote ' before parsing with csv.reader - however, I would like to know if there is a better way without modifying the original data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is that you need to define an [escapechar](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.escapechar), so that the csv reader knows to treat \" as ".

```
csv.reader(csv_file, quotechar='"', delimiter=',', escapechar='\\')
```

Comment: That works! I was reading through the same documentation for a good while and don't know how I missed that! I guess I was focusing on the wrong thing (quotechar). Thanks.

Comment: This should work too: `csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",", quotechar="\"")`. At least it does not coplain in my case. @ Greg You were faster xD

Comment: @BCJuan I did try "\"" first, but that did not work as it literally just passes one single quotation mark and results in the same parsing errors.  To get the backslash in you have to put in two \\ backslashes first but then it would complain about it not being a single character.

Comment: I have tried it with the sample sentence and it works for me :/

Comment: @BCJuan, hm you are right, I was not testing with the sample set above but with my actual data set.  With the sample set your approach seems to work, but with my actual data set it does not.  The only other difference I can see is that my actual dataset also includes new line breaks, perhaps the combination of both the escape char and new lines is what breaks it?